# Merge S3 files into multiple <1GB S3 files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I have multiple S3 files in a bucket.

```
Input S3 bucket : 
File1 - 2GB data
File 2 - 500MB data
File 3 - 1Gb Data
file 4 - 2GB data
```

and so on. Assume there are 50 such files. Data within files is of same schema, lets say `attribute1, attribute 2`.

I want to merge these files and output into a new bucket as follows, such that each file is less than 1GB in same schema as before.

```
Files 1 - < 1GB 
Files 2 - < 1GB
Files 3 - < 1GB
```

I am looking for AWS based solutions which I can deliver using AWS CDK. I was considering following two solutions :

1. AWS Athena - reads and writes to S3 but not sure if I can set up a 1GB limit while writing.
2. AWS Lambda - read file sequentially, store in memory, when size is near 1GB, write to new file in s3 bucket. Repeat until all files completed. I'm worried about the 15 min timeout, not sure if lambda will be able to process.

Expected scales -> Overall file input size sum : 1 TB

What would be a good way to go about implementing this? Hope I have phrased the question right, I'd be happy to comment if any doubts.

Thanks!

Edit :
Based on a comment ->
Apologies for calling it a merge. More of a reset. All files have the same schema, placed in csv files. In terms of pseudo code

```
    List<Files> listOfFiles = ReadFromS3(key)
    New file named temp.csv
    for each file : listOfFiles : 
        append file to temp.csv
    List<1GBGiles> finalList = Break down temp.csv into sets of 1GB each
    for(File file : finalList) 
        writeToS3(finalList)
```

Comment: Could you please give a bit more context on what you're trying to do? For instance if I read this question I wonder: a) WHy would you want to do that in the first place? What do you mean by merge? If I merge two files with 1GB of data each, how could I get a file that is less than 1GB? I am guessing you need some type of processing..please explain, maybe with some pseudo-code so that we can give you some alternative options.

Comment: @AR1 have added pseudo code. If I had an EC2 instance, I could store `temp.csv` in memory. Looking for other ways around this problem

Answer (score 2):

Amazon Athena can run a query across multiple objects in a given Amazon S3 path, as long as they all have the same format (eg same columns in a CSV file).

It can store the result in a new External Table, with a location pointing to an S3 bucket, by using a `CREATE TABLE AS` command and a `LOCATION` parameter.

The size of the output files can be controlled by setting the number of **output buckets** (which is *not* the same as an S3 bucket).

See:

- [Bucketing vs partitioning - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/bucketing-vs-partitioning.html)
- [Set the number or size of files for a CTAS query in Amazon Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/set-file-number-size-ctas-athena/)

Comment: Thanks Athena does sound good. In case I need to run some logic, such as adding some attributes to file/serialization of json, I would not be able to use Athena. Any alternates to it?

Answer (score 0):

If your process includes ETL(Extraction Transformation Load) post process, you could use [AWS GLUE](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/?whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc)
Please find [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/ug/edit-jobs-source-s3-files.html) an example for Glue using s3 as a source.
If you’d like to use it with Java SDK, the best starting points are:

- [the Glue GitHub repo](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/glue)
- [The aws Java code sample catalog for Glue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/code-catalog-javav2-example_code-glue.html)

Out of all of them your the Tutorial to [create a crawler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/ug/tutorial-add-crawler.html) (that you can find in GitHub as per above url) should match your case as it crawls an S3 bucket and put it in a glue catalog for transformation.

Comment: Thanks! Follow up, if I have to use clients written in java SDK, how can I integrate them in glue? Would I need to somehow sideload these jars?

Comment: @DhruvRatanGupta I enriched my previous answer to include the clarification you were looking for. Please accept or upvote the answer if it solves your problem.